# How can I have the end-user trigger a second approval process within the same Object manually?

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I have an interesting question for you guys...

- I have two different approval processes associated with one Object and per different field criteria, they trigger accordingly...
- I also have two flows that trigger them automatically without having the user to click the "Submit for Approval" Button.

Here's where the issue comes in;

- one of the flows is set to see if a specific field is empty or not, if it's not empty, it triggers itself activating the second approval process...
- I realized however that the approval process has initiated for the first time through the flow, if they need to recall the approval process, change something and relaunch the approval process...

  - it won't let them relaunch the flow.
- The default "Submit for Approval" button activates the first approval process I build which makes sense.

Changing what's in the field also doesn't trigger the flow and making the field empty, saving the record, then populating the field again also doesn't trigger to flow because

- the flow is set to "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements" and
- I cannot choose the "Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements" because it'll trigger every time the record is manipulated if there's something in the field...

I can't figure out a solution for this...I can't create a quick action button because it's a record-trigger flow...do you guys have any ideas on how to have them launch the approval process manually if they need to??

Many many thanks for any ideas you guys may have and stay awesome!